# Remove every line that include and follows the second occurrence of a given pattern

Tags: strings, regex, bash, awk, sed

From a file, I am trying to remove every line that include and follows the second occurrence of a given pattern in Bash (Mac OSX). Note, that a file may have only one match of the given pattern (and so nothing need to be removed).

Here an example of file

```
bar
second
third
fourth
bar
sixth
```

and here is a code that does the job

```
# Find the index of the second occurrence
i=$(grep -nrH ${pattern} ${file} | awk -F':' '{if (NR==2)print $2}')

# If there was a second occurrence, then remove everything that followed it
if [[ ${i} != "" ]];then
    head -n $(( ${i} - 1 )) ${file} > tmp && mv tmp ${file};
fi
```

The resulting file is

```
bar
second
third
fourth
```

Is there a more elegant or faster solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be pretty speedy:

```
awk '/bar/ {n++} n==2 {exit} {print}' file
```

To pass the pattern from the shell:

```
awk -v p="$pattern" '$0 ~ p {n++} n==2 {exit} {print}' file
```

Comment: Generally, if you find yourself mixing grep and awk and sed in a pipeline, you can replace all of it with a single awk program.

Comment: You could write a bit shorter by replacing `{print}` with `1`, for example `awk '/bar/ {n++} n==2 {exit} 1' file`